# Overwrite file on server (PHP)

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, overwrite, unlink

I am making an Android application that need to be able to push files onto a server.

For this I'm using `POST` and `fopen/fwrite` but this method only appends to the file and using `unlink` before writing to the file has no effect. (`file_put_contents` has the exact same effect)

This is what I have so far

```
<?php
$fileContent = $_POST['filecontent'];

$relativePath = "/DatabaseFiles/SavedToDoLists/".$_POST['filename'];
$savePath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$relativePath; 

unlink($savePath);

$file = fopen($savePath,"w");
fwrite($file,$fileContent);
fclose($file);

?>
```

The file will correctly delete its self when I don't try and write to it after but if I do try and write to it, it will appended.

Anyone got any suggestions on overwriting the file contents?

Thanks, Luke.

Comment: No way this could be happening. fopen in `w` mode is "open file, truncate to zero length". If it was appending, you'd have to be opening in `a` mode

Answer (score 12):

Use `wa+` for opening and truncating:

```
$file = fopen($savePath,"wa+");
```

[fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

> **w+**: Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> **a+**: Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. As the manual says: it truncates to 0 length.

Comment: i was using string = string + newString and forgetting to call string = "" before clicking save a second time so it was just adding the new ones on each time

Answer (score 7):

```
file_put_contents($savePath,$fileContent);
```

Will overwrite the file or create if not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

read this it will help show all the options for fopen

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score -1):

Found the error, i forgot to reset a string inside of my application